# Is there a bug somewhere with the flagging system?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flagging

I just raised a single flag for spam on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589170/best-bodybuilding-diet-regime) question, and when clicking the flag button again the popup shows this:

[image]

But I just flagged the question once, and accordingly I still have 9 flags available to be raised today. Is there a bug somewhere with the flagging system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's the normal behaviour. Spam and offensive flags are functionally the same, the only difference being [how the labelled data is used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work):

> ### How does the Spam flag differ from the Offensive flag?
>
> In terms of getting the post deleted, there is no functional difference aside from separate counts - 3/6 of either will be sufficient to delete. Spam flags provide data for spam-filtering, and offensive flags similarly provide data for anti-trolling measures.

The notice placed over a deleted post also says much the same (*spam or offensive*):

[image]

Comment: Should have read something about the topic before posting. Thanks

Comment: @kos no, its all right, this way more people (like me) learn about that difference :)